# Mongoose how to sort by sum of an embedded array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a course collection, and an array in it stores count of rating 1-5 of the course. Such as [0, 3, 0, 0, 1] means 3 people vote 2 stars and one votes 5 stars.
How can I sort by the final score using mongoose? I mean first calculate the (a + 2b + 3c + 4d + 5e) / (a + b + c + d + e) as the score, then sort the collection？

```
const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  courseName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  rateCount: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true,
    default: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  }
}
```

Comment: Also see [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to add the values together from an array. You would be far better off keeping the total in the document instead of calculating.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, I think I should add a starCount and a rateCount, just divide them and then sort?

Comment: If you "need" a calculation at run-time, then do what is demonstrated in the linked question, where you use `aggregate()` to project a new value and sort on it. If your calculation is "static", then it makes sense to keep it in the document since calculation costs. That's just tacking on some wisdom and general sense. But you go do whatever you want to do.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks, I'll try to store it.